# Go - Parse timestamp with unknown number of digits for day and hour

Tags: go, parsing, timestamp

Say I have a timestamp that looks like this:
`Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04:05 PM`

But the day of the month, as well as the hour of the day can either be one or two digits.
So there can be something like `Jan 12, 2006 at 12:04:05 PM`

So far the best I could come up with is try parsing (with `time.Parse`) with 4 distinct layouts:

- `Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04:05 PM`
- `Jan _2, 2006 at 3:04:05 PM`
- `Jan 2, 2006 at 15:04:05 PM`
- `Jan _2, 2006 at 15:04:05 PM`

Is there a simpler way to do this in Go?

Comment: The `_` space formatter is really for outputting time (i.e. `time.Format`) with the desired spacing, it is not used for time inputs i.e. `time.Parse`

Comment: Use any one of the layouts.  https://go.dev/play/p/P8dpqecaRlb

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the old-fashioned way myself and parse the bits out with a regular expression, if for no other reason than than the indeterminance of receiving something like "Oct 29, 2008 at 15:34:12 AM". What exactly does that mean?

```
func parse(s string) (dt time.Time, err error) {
  matches := rxDateTime.FindStringSubmatch(s)
  
  if matches == nil {
    return dt, errors.New("Invalid Date/Time string")
  }
  
  month     := strings.ToUpper( matches[mmm]  )
  day, _    := strconv.Atoi(    matches[dd]   )
  year, _   := strconv.Atoi(    matches[yyyy] )
  hour, _   := strconv.Atoi(    matches[hh]   )
  minute, _ := strconv.Atoi(    matches[mm]   )
  second, _ := strconv.Atoi(    matches[ss]   )
  ampm      := strings.ToUpper( matches[ampm] )
  
  if hour < 12 && ampm == "PM" {
    hour += 12
  } else if hour >= 12 && ampm == "AM" {
    hour -= 12
  }
  
  dt = time.Date(year, monthNum[month], day, hour, minute, second, 0, localTime)
  return dt, err
}

var monthNum = map[string]time.Month{
  "JAN": time.January,
  "FEB": time.February,
  "MAR": time.March,
  "APR": time.April,
  "MAY": time.May,
  "JUN": time.June,
  "JUL": time.July,
  "AUG": time.August,
  "SEP": time.September,
  "OCT": time.October,
  "NOV": time.November,
  "DEC": time.December,
}
var localTime, _ = time.LoadLocation("Local")

var rxDateTime = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)(?P<mmm>Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(?P<dd>\d+)\s*,\s*(?P<yyyy>\d+)\s+AT\s+(?P<hh>\d+):(?P<mm>\d+):(?P<ss>\d+)\s*(?P<ampm>AM|PM)`)

var mmm  = rxDateTime.SubexpIndex( "mmm"  )
var dd   = rxDateTime.SubexpIndex( "dd"   )
var yyyy = rxDateTime.SubexpIndex( "yyyy" )
var hh   = rxDateTime.SubexpIndex( "hh"   )
var mm   = rxDateTime.SubexpIndex( "mm"   )
var ss   = rxDateTime.SubexpIndex( "ss"   )
var ampm = rxDateTime.SubexpIndex( "ampm" )
```

See https://go.dev/play/p/Uo3GbqUywxA